Nginx proxying lost Tomcat's HTTP port
===========================10.10.50.95===========================

I am running a Tomcat on the machine at 10.10.50.95


Locally, I verified the service is running normally using curl

curl -v http://10.10.50.95:8080/7602
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 10.10.50.95...
* Connected to 10.10.50.95 (10.10.50.95) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /7602 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: 10.10.50.95:8080
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 
< Location: /7602/
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Tue, 16 Apr 2024 12:21:13 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host 10.10.50.95 left intact

The verification result is as above, okay!

===========================10.10.50.60===========================

I added a configuration to the Nginx on the machine at 10.10.50.60 (external IP: 120.133.138.171)

sudo vi /opt/nginx1.10.2/conf/vhosts/mig.conf
upstream mig {
    server 10.10.50.95:8080;
}

server {
    listen 11195;
    server_name 120.133.138.171;

    location / {
        proxy_read_timeout 300s;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Port $server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://mig;
        #Testing with the following configuration added did not resolve the issue
        #proxy_redirect ~^http://120.133.138.171(/.*)$ http://$host:11195$1;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/mig_err.log info;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/mig_access.log access;
}

nginx -s reload
The result verification failed.
curl -v http://120.133.138.171:11195/7602
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 120.133.138.171...
* Connected to 120.133.138.171 (120.133.138.171) port 11195 (#0)
> GET /7602 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: 120.133.138.171:11195
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 
* Server nginx is not blacklisted
< Server: nginx
< Date: Tue, 16 Apr 2024 12:26:08 GMT
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: http://120.133.138.171/7602/
< 
* Connection #0 to host 120.133.138.171 left intact

Why did the 302 redirect lose port 11195 ?????
